# Google sign in using firebase working on emulator but not on real device?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Sign in works perfectly in emulator but it is always failing on my real android phones.
`task.isSuccessful()` always returns a false result in my real device but no problem when I am using the emulator.

```
package com.inc.mountzoft.goldencompass;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//a constant for detecting the login intent result
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 234;

//Tag for the logs optional
private static final String TAG = "firebaseAuthentication";

//creating a GoogleSignInClient object
GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;

//And also a Firebase Auth object
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
GoogleSignInAccount account;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    //first we intialized the FirebaseAuth object
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //Then we need a GoogleSignInOptions object
    //And we need to build it as below
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    //Then we will get the GoogleSignInClient object from GoogleSignIn class
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    //Now we will attach a click listener to the sign_in_button
    //and inside onClick() method we are calling the signIn() method that will open
    //google sign in intent
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            signIn();
        }
    });
}




@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    //if the requestCode is the Google Sign In code that we defined at starting
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {

        //Getting the GoogleSignIn Task
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            //Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);

            //authenticating with firebase
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Signing In...Please Wait !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Try again !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

    //getting the auth credential
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);

    //Now using firebase we are signing in the user here
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
```

**//task.isSuccessful() is always returns a false result in my real device but no problem when i am using emulator.**

```
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Welcome, you are signed as "+account.getDisplayName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            });
}


//this method is called on click
private void signIn() {
    //getting the google signin intent
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();

    //starting the activity for result
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
  }
}
```

Comment: what error or exception message it is showing ?

Comment: 'task.getException()' returns 
       "com.google.firebase.FirebaseNetworkException: A network error ( such as time out, interrupted connection or unreachable host ) has occurred."

Comment: It can also happen when google play services are not running. Try to launch play store and check if it is working. If not reboot of device issue.And also compare the google play services using in the project and google play services in the device are same if not update google play services.

This is just a minor but possible case where it gives the exception.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't say it states that the user doesn't exist. I think it implies there is something wrong with the connection -> phone is offline, server is down, server didn't respond, etc

Comment: In my phone play-services version is 11.9.51 but in my project play-services version is 11.8.0. So i changed play-services version in my project from 11.8.0 to 11.9.51 and sync the project. But now the problem is "could not find dependency com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth: 11.9.51"

Comment: first check your internet connection in device , and download latest gms play services in your project