# Cannot open sign in activity by google

Tags: java, android, google-signin

I cannot open sign in activity by google. That's my app code.

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();

            mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
    SignInButton signInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
            signInButton.setOnClickListener(view -> signIn());

private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(task);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
        try {
            account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            Log.w("Err", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
        }
    }
```

I tried with different RC_SIGN_IN codes like 901, 1 but still no solution.

Comment: Have you checked what is the exception ?

Comment: I didn't get exception.. The activity is starting to appear and then just disappear.

Comment: I debug it and still no exception

Comment: Why you are not using firebase ?

Comment: reportFullscreenMode on inexistent InputConnection that is the message that appear when I click on the button, but it is not appearing like mistake

Comment: onActivityResult method returns for requestCode 1, for resultCode -1 and for data "Intent { (has extras) }".. any ideas @AdityaSonel

Comment: Is your app registered on google developers or not ? because to enable sign in you have to register your application.

Comment: yes, it is registered, it is uploaded to google play also

Comment: I got the error your GoogleApiClient is not registered for Auth Api. Just register it.

Comment: it is registered in google api console with credentials and all the stuff.. I added code from firebase also, but the first time I just copy the code, it works, but now I can... Then I delete all code and start again but I cannot open this activity for result

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use code as,

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .build();

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
         .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,gso)
         .build();

signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
        });
```

onActivityResult,

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }
```

handleSigninResult,

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
       Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
       if (result.isSuccess()) {
           // Signed in successfolly, show authenticated UI.
       } 
   }
```

Comment: still not working, can you tell me the rc_sign_in value

Comment: maybe it is problem, hopefully

Answer (score 0):

Try This link make a layout in xml format and define button to click it for Google sign in . Make sign in button in your activity and mention this activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` as launcher or on startup

[Google sign in using firebase working on emulator but not on real device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48017356/google-sign-in-using-firebase-working-on-emulator-but-not-on-real-device)
Link these activity with xml with login.java activity and button design in xml . 
Also mention activity whom you want to move after Google sign in

Comment: Click on blue text it is Title of that link